# Print Name Near Detected Face in Opencv?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I need to print a name/text near the face detected face rectangle below  is my code to detect face. Can anyone suggest me a method to do that?

```
webSource.retrieve(frame);
Graphics g = jPanel2.getGraphics();
MatOfRect faceDetections =   new MatOfRect();
faceDetector.detectMultiScale(frame, faceDetections);
Rect rectCrop = null;
for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
     System.out.println("ttt");
     Core.rectangle(frame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
     new Scalar(0, 255,0));
     rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y,125, 150);

     //faceDetector.detectMultiScale(frame, faceDetections);
     int fcz= faceDetections.toArray().length;
     System.out.println("fcz="+fcz);
     System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));
}
```

Comment: You can write text in an image Mat with org.opencv.core.Core.putText

Comment: do you already know whom you did detect (so you recognized a person) and only want to print it, or did you only detect "any" face and don't know how to recognize the person?

Comment: thanku #jose it worked

Comment: Try to post formatted code to make it more readable

Answer (score 1):

i used Core.putText and it worked below is my code for that

```
Core.putText(frame,"Name", new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,10,new Scalar(0, 255,0));
```